# SQL join and multiple count(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `groups_areas`, `groups`, `groups_members`, `groups_logs` tables.
I want to list all groups in an area, with the description etc coming from `groups` and the stats from `groups_members` and `groups_logs`. Here is my I have:

```
SELECT name, description
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN groups_areas ga ON ga.groupid = g.id WHERE ga.area = ?; 

SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM groups_members gm
WHERE gm.groupid = ?) as members,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM groups_logs gl WHERE gl.groupid = ?) as logs;
```

The problem, as I see it, is that I need to somehow correlate each group id from the first query with the group id of the second set of sub-queries. Giving me a result set of `name, description, members, logs` for each group in the area.

Table Structure (simplified):

groups

```
id (int) | name (text) | description (text)
1          engineering   building things
2          sociology     study of people
3          mining        digging up the earth
4          economics     study of various economic processes
```

groups_areas

```
groupid (int) | area (int)
1             2
2             2
3             1
4             3
```

groups_members

```
groupid (int) | member (int)
1             1
1             2
2             3
4             3
3             2
3             1
```

groups_logs

```
groupid (int) | log (int)
1             1
2             4
3             2
3             3
4             5
```

members

```
id (int) | name (text)
1          max
2          john
3          elf
```

Expected output would be a rows like:

```
engineering | building things       | 2  | 1
mining | digging up the earth | 2 | 2
...
```

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Postgresql here?

Comment: could you please share your table structure?

Comment: no jarlh, changed the tag

Comment: 1) What do you mean by stats? 2) Pls provide sample data and expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: By stats I mean the two `count(*)`.

Comment: Is that enough sample data?

Comment: That's not sample data, that's expected output only. Show us the data in the tables that would produce the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using left joins and distinct counts.

```sql
SELECT g.name, g.description, 
COUNT(DISTINCT gm.member) AS members, 
COUNT(DISTINCT gl.log) AS logs
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN groups_areas ga ON (ga.groupid = g.id)
LEFT JOIN groups_members gm ON (gm.groupid = g.id)
LEFT JOIN groups_logs gl ON (gl.groupid = g.id)
WHERE ga.area = ?
GROUP BY g.name, g.description
ORDER BY g.name, g.description;
```

Or without a group by. Joining to subqueries.
This might be slower when looking for one area, but might be faster for all areas.

```
SELECT g.name, g.description, 
gm.total as members, 
gl.total as logs
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN groups_areas ga ON (ga.groupid = g.id)
LEFT JOIN (
  select groupid, count(distinct member) as total 
  from groups_members
  group by groupid
) gm ON (gm.groupid = g.id)
LEFT JOIN (
  select groupid, count(distinct log) as total 
  from groups_logs
  group by groupid
) gl ON (gl.groupid = g.id)
WHERE ga.area = ?
ORDER BY g.name, g.description;
```

Test data

```
create table groups (id int PRIMARY KEY, name text, description text);
insert into groups values (1,'engineering','building things');
insert into groups values (2,'sociology','study of people');
insert into groups values (3,'mining','digging up the earth');
insert into groups values (4,'economics','study of various economic processes');

create table groups_areas (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, groupid int, area int);
insert into groups_areas (groupid, area) values (1,2);
insert into groups_areas (groupid, area) values (2,2);
insert into groups_areas (groupid, area) values (3,1);
insert into groups_areas (groupid, area) values (4,3);

create table groups_members (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, groupid int, member int);
insert into groups_members (groupid, member) values (1,1);
insert into groups_members (groupid, member) values (1,2);
insert into groups_members (groupid, member) values (2,3);
insert into groups_members (groupid, member) values (4,3);
insert into groups_members (groupid, member) values (3,2);
insert into groups_members (groupid, member) values (3,1);

create table groups_logs (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, groupid int, log int);
insert into groups_logs (groupid, log) values (1,1);
insert into groups_logs (groupid, log) values (2,4);
insert into groups_logs (groupid, log) values (3,2);
insert into groups_logs (groupid, log) values (3,3);
insert into groups_logs (groupid, log) values (4,5);
```

Comment: They two give different results for me, the second works fine. Thanks

Comment: Modified them a bit. Instead of the on the id fields they now both count distinct on that log and member id.  Both gave the same results based on your test data.

Comment: They both work. I wrote it out a few times, hardcode it into memory, makes sense. Thanks again.